# Laravel 5.6 Flexible Relationship Spanning Differing Tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[image: EER Diagram]

I have a table which will be addressed by a model in Laravel for stock movements. I would like to establish a relates to field which can be related to a number of different tables.

As per the attached diagram I need the relates_to_id to be one of the following...

- Purchases.purchase_id
- Invoices.invoice_id

And there may be more being added in the future as we find more records which may result in a stock movement occurring.

Now I have added a relates_to_type field to the database schema for the stock movements table so that I can specify which record type the particular movement record relates to. But I have been struggling to figure out how to establish the model for such a relationship to work or if it will even work that way or if I will need to have a separate field for each type of relationship as I wish to be able to read the related record through the ORM's related record scheme.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact use case for [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships), they supply your model as you wished for with an column indicating the relation type and the id of the related model.

See also this example from the laravel documentation:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model {
  /**
   * Get all of the owning imageable models.
   */
  public function imageable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}

class Post extends Model {
  /**
   * Get the post's image.
   */
  public function image(){
    return $this->morphOne('App\Image', 'imageable');
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  /**
   * Get the user's image.
   */
  public function image()
  {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Image', 'imageable');
  }
}
```

Here every user and post can have an image and every image has an imageable which is either a user or a post.